# Only terminal window resizing in Awesome WM

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I am using awesome window manager (new to it). The normal keybinding for changing size for the window in tiling mode is Super+h & Super+L but it only resizes the terminal window (I am using alacrity & it is resizing that), but if I try to resize another window instance firefox, it is not resizing that. Any solution will be appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats for newcomers. Also this is a related question: [What is incwfact and setwfact of awesome.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629473/what-is-incwfact-and-setwfact-of-awesome-client)

Basically what you need is hidden in this documentation page:
https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/tag.html

`incmwfact`: Increase master width factor

And here: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html

`incwfact`: Change window factor of a client.

Example from my config:

`K.win` is the `Mod4` Key which is the windows key on my keyboard.
I'm "expanding" the current window (client) to the location indicated by the arrow key. Actually I'd need some extra code for up/down to work correctly in all cases but I rarely have vertically stacked windows.

```lua
awful.key(
    {K.win},
    "Right",
    function()
        awful.tag.incmwfact(0.05)
    end,
),
awful.key(
    {K.win},
    "Left",
    function()
        awful.tag.incmwfact(-0.05)
    end,
),
awful.key(
    {K.win},
    "Down",
    function()
        awful.client.incwfact(-0.05)
    end,
),
awful.key(
    {K.win},
    "Up",
    function()
        awful.client.incwfact(0.05)
    end,
),
```